# SSH to localhost keeps asking for password on MacBook Air M1

Tags: macos, ssh, mac, hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop on my MacBook Air M1 and when I write start-all.sh in terminal it prompts

```
fatix@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

I did following steps to generate ssh keys:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 id_rsa
```

Change my config file like this :

```
Host *
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Yet, when I type ssh localhost it asks for password. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try running ssh with the "-vv" flag to print debugging output, then [edit] your question to include the ssh command that you ran and the debugging output. It would also be helpful to run "ls -la .ssh" and include the output in your question.

Comment: @Kenster edited....

Comment: Please edit your question: What version of macOS are you using? The fact this is an M1 Mac is meaningless; this is an OS issue. Also, `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` the `.ssh` directory and `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the `authorized_keys` file. I don’t believe `chmod 600 id_rsa` is needed.